# Batch File to Delete File

Tags: file, batch-file

Can someone please help me to make a batch file to delete files beginning with the name **Stock Level** which are .csv files stored in C:\Windows\Temp folder.

I would like to test it first to see what it proposes to delete before I make it live so if someone can show may what I need to delete to make it live as well.

Thanks very much in advance for your help.

Roy

Comment: Make a backup of `C:\Windows\Temp` and just run `del "C:\Windows\Temp\Stock Level*.csv"`?

Answer (score 1):

As a batch file,

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%a in ("c:\windows\temp\stock level*.csv") do echo(del "%%a"
```

should generate your list by executing `echo("%%a"` for `%%a` set to each filenme matching the mask supplied.

If the result is correct, simply remove the `echo(` part to activate the `del`